# How can I use friend classes with inheritance and templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, friend

I've got a special configuration to build and I don't know how to write this :

```
template <typename VarType>
class A
{
  protected:
    VarType m_myVar;
}

template <typename VarType>
class B : public A<VarType>
{
}

class C : public B<SpecialType>
{
  void DoSomething()
  {
    m_myVar.PrivateFunction();
  }
}

class SpecialType
{
  private:
    void PrivateFunction()
    {
      //Do something
    }
}
```

How can I use the keyword *friend* to make it work ??

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: No semicolons after *any* of your class declarations. Good luck with compilation ;-)

Comment: I feel sorry for whoever has to maintain that abomination :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare `C` as friend of `SpecialType`...

```
class SpecialType
{
  private:
    friend class C;
    void PrivateFunction()
    {
      //Do something
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world, you could perhaps write   `friend  C::DoSomething();` inside the SpecialType class decl, 
but alas no, your only option seems to be `friend class C;` (as per nyrl)

friends and forward declarations of incomplete types doesn't play as nicely as we might hope.